# Perl DBI dynamic fetchrow while loops

Tags: perl, dynamic, loops, dbi, while-loop

I'm trying to pass table names to a sub that gets all the field names of that table, stores them into an array, and then uses that array in conjunction with the fetchrow of another sql query to display the data in those fields.  Here's the code I have now:

Examples of sub calls with table names as the parameter:

```
shamoo("reqhead_rec");
shamoo("approv_rec");
shamoo("denial_rec");
```

shamoo sub:

```
sub shamoo
{
    my $table = shift;
    print uc($table)."\n=====================================\n";

    #takes arg (table name) and stores all the field names into an array
    $STMT = <<EOF;
    select first 1 * from $table
    EOF

    my $sth = $db1->prepare($STMT);$sth->execute;

    my ($i, @field);
    my $columns = $sth->{NAME_lc};
    while (my $row = $sth->fetch){for $i (0 .. $#$row){$field[$i] = $columns->[$i];}}

    $STMT = <<EOF;
    select * from $table where frm = '$frm' and req_no = $req_no
    EOF
    $sth = $db1->prepare($STMT);$sth->execute;
    $i=0;
    while ($i!=scalar(@field))
    {
    #need code for in here...
    }
}
```

I am looking for a way to turn this nto something that doesn't have to be explicitly defined....

```
my ($frm, $req_no, $auth_id, $alt_auth_id, $id_acct, $seq_no, $id, $appr_stat, $add_date, $approve_date, $approve_time, $prim);
while(($frm, $req_no, $auth_id, $alt_auth_id, $id_acct, $seq_no, $id, $appr_stat, $add_date, $approve_date, $approve_time, $prim) = $sth->fetchrow_array())
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use fetchrow_hashref:

```
sub shamoo {
    my ($dbh, $frm, $req_no, $table) = @_;

    print uc($table), "\n", "=" x 36, "\n";

    #takes arg (table name) and stores all the field names into an array
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare(
        "select * from $table where frm = ? and req_no = ?"
    );

    $sth->execute($frm, $req_no);

    my $i = 1;
    while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
        print "row ", $i++, "\n";
        for my $col (keys %$row) {
            print "\t$col is $row->{$col}\n";
        }
    }
}
```

You may also want to set `FetchHashKeyName` to `"NAME_lc"` or `"NAME_uc"` when you create your database handle:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    $dsn,
    $user,
    $pass,
    {
        ChopBlanks       => 1,
        AutoCommit       => 1,
        PrintError       => 0,
        RaiseError       => 1,
        FetchHashKeyName => "NAME_lc",
    }
) or die DBI->errstr;
```

Comment: (keys %$row) gives me this - Global symbol "%row" requires explicit package name at ./req.pl

Comment: The print in the for should be:

print "\t$col is $row->{ $col }\n";

Comment: Whoops, that is what I get for not testing.

Comment: Could be worth mentioning to set FetchHashKeyName when calling DBI->connect to iron out gotchas with possibly-case-insensitive uppercase/lowercase column names being used as case-sensitive hash keys. So for instance I always connect specifying FetchHashKeyName => 'NAME_lc' so that the hash keys representing the column names are guaranteed to be lower case, even if the DB returns them CamelCased.

Comment: @araqnid I was adding that while you were leaving the comment.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if this method would work for an empty table.

The safest method to get the column metadata is not to look at the keys of the returned hashref (which might not exist) but rather play by the rules and use DBI provided attributes of $sth itself:

```
$sth->{NAME}->[i]
$sth->{NAME_uc}->[i]
$sth->{NAME_lc}->[i]
```

See the Metadata section of the DBI man page for details.